# why can we lock a mutex defined inside a const object?

Tags: c++, c++11, synchronization, constants, mutable

Working case:

```
template<typename T>
class threadsafe_queue
{
private:
    mutable std::mutex mut;
    std::queue<T> data_queue;

public:
    threadsafe_queue()
    {}

    threadsafe_queue(const threadsafe_queue& other)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(other.mut);
        data_queue=other.data_queue;
    }
};
```

Case that should fail: Note no `mutable` on `std::mutex mut;`

```
template<typename T>
class threadsafe_queue
{
private:
    std::mutex mut;
    std::queue<T> data_queue;

public:
    threadsafe_queue()
    {}

    threadsafe_queue(const threadsafe_queue& other)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(other.mut);
        data_queue=other.data_queue;
    }
};
```

I have tried the both cases listed above and they compile without problems. I assume internally the lock_guard calls mutex::lock function which itself is NOT a const function.

Question> why can we lock the mutex from a const object in the copy constructor?

Comment: Surely the `mutable` is the key here?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Look at the second version, where the `mutable` keyword is gone. The questioner reports that that version works too.

Comment: @user2357112 - It doesn't really work though: http://ideone.com/2MVs0O

Comment: Without using mutable, it still compiles. Please see here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d95332d6b7f5766f

Comment: @q0987: Probably because you never actually performed template instantiation.

Comment: @q0987: It only compiles since the compiler (mostly) ignores your uninstantiated template class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **first** example compiles  because the mutex is qualified to be [`mutable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/mutable). That means that this field can be modified, mutated, without the containing object considered to have been changed. So, in a sense, the mutex' state is not "part of the queue". The compiler allows `const` methods to modify `mutable` members.

The **second** example only compiles as long as you don't actually try to instantiate the class and use that method. If you do, [it fails](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/debd6d305a550cf7). Templates are magic...

Comment: Look at the second version, where the `mutable` keyword is gone. The questioner reports that that version works too.

Comment: The second is an ill formed program, because no `T` permists instantiation if the template function that is legal.  However, no diagnostic is required, so compilers are free to compile it and ignore it.  I believe this rule exists to permit, but not require, compilers to generate additional diagnostics.  The actual impact of this rule interpreted literally is ridiculous, as the standard mandates no behaviour restrictions on ill formed programs...